# How do you stop internet explorer from caching API calls?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching

I'm having weird Internet explorer bug where my web app is not returning an expected api response, but it works in other browsers.

It does not seem to be a javascript error and it looks like it might be a caching issue for IE where it is caching the api response.

How do I ensure that IE is not caching and returning my ajax call?

Comment: Start with setting the proper headers on the api!

Comment: For just a testing, You can try to use setting mentioned in link below in IE 11 to prevent caching. which can help to narrow down the issue. http://docs.netapp.com/sgws-110/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.netapp.doc.sg-app-install%2FGUID-1E34D79A-2EB8-4A0D-AA47-E7BB62B8C77B.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the cache-control header:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234067/how-to-prevent-caching-in-internet-explorer

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
<% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```

If you're using an older version of IE that ignores cache-control, or what to be super sure that there's no caching, one kind of hacky but pretty common way to break the cache is the change the URL header to have a unique generated url-parameter.

A random number, a timestamp, or a uuid would all work for this purpose.

`www.mywebsite.com/api-endpoint?_=<GeneratedId>`

where `<GeneratedId>` is replaced.